# Как замерять производительность кода в продакшне?

Tags: highload, benchmark

Есть бекенд, на котором крутится много веб-приложений.
Хочется достичь двух целей:
1. Снизить время генерации страницы, чтобы гугл и юзеры полюбили наш сайт.
2. Снизить потребление ресурсов CPU, чтобы меньше бекендов нужно было.

Так вот внедряя разные оптимизации в коде мы обычно делаем разные замеры.
Чаще всего замеряем просто среднее кол-во времени, необходимое на обработку одного http-запроса.

Среднее за сутки, т.к. за бОльшее кол-во времени слишком долго ждать. Ну и вообще хотелось бы как-то сделать так, чтобы и суток не нужно было ждать - посмотрел 5 минут, пособирал данные, вычислил среднее, и делаешь вывод - улучшилась производительность или ухудшилась.

Так вот время выполнения сферического алгоритма зависит в т.ч. от нагрузки на сервер. Т.е. можно что-то изменить в коде, выкатить в продакшн, и увидеть, что нагрузка изменилась не в ту сторону, в которую на самом деле изменилась эффективность алгоритма, т.к. просто сейчас часпик или день недели такой, что много запросов отправляют пользователи.

Я попробовал замерять только юзерское время (как утилита time замеряет).
Но когда сервер загружен не на 100%, эта метрика так же чувствительна на загруженности сервера (полупустой сервер работает почти в 2 раза быстрее, чем загруженный на 100%).

Загрузкой на 100% здесь можно считать выполнение стольки однопоточных процессов, съедающих всё доступное время процессора, сколько физических процессорных ядер есть на сервере.
Т.е. там, где включен hyperthreading, нужно запустить таких процессов в 2 раза меньше, чем видно ядер, а где выключен - столько же, сколько видно ядер.

Вот так я замерял:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes qw(time);

my $forks = shift;

my $lscpu = `lscpu`;
my($cpus) = $lscpu =~ /^CPU\(s\):\s+(\d)$/m;
my($threadsPerCore) = $lscpu =~ /^Thread\(s\) per core:\s+(\d)$/m;
my $cores = $cpus / $threadsPerCore;

sub load {
    my $a = 0;
    $a += rand() foreach(0 .. 100000000)
}

fork() for (1 .. $forks);

my $u = - times();
my $t = - time();
load();
$u += times();
$t += time();


printf "| %d | %d | %d | %.2f | %.2f |\n", $cpus, $cores, 2 ** $forks, $t, $u;
```

И вот мои замеры на машине с hyperthreading:

```
|----|-----|-----|-------|---------|
|CPUs|Cores|Procs| Time  |User time|
|----|-----|-----|-------|---------|
|  4 |  2  |  1  | 11.08 |  11.07  |
|  4 |  2  |  2  | 11.70 |  11.69  |
|  4 |  2  |  4  | 19.79 |  19.64  |
|  4 |  2  |  8  | 39.42 |  19.62  |
|  4 |  2  |  16 | 83.36 |  19.86  |
|----|-----|-----|-------|---------|
```

И на машине без hyperthreading:

```
|----|-----|-----|-------|---------|
|CPUs|Cores|Procs| Time  |User time|
|----|-----|-----|-------|---------|
|  2 |  2  |  1  | 23.74 |  23.73  |
|  2 |  2  |  2  | 23.53 |  23.52  |
|  2 |  2  |  4  | 46.78 |  23.38  |
|  2 |  2  |  8  | 93.76 |  23.43  |
|----|-----|-----|-------|---------|
```

И на этой машине User time везде примерно одинаков!
Но что же не так с первой машиной? Как только я загружаю на ней больше физических ядер, чем у неё есть, user time увеличивается.
Это что? Магия hyperthreading? Но ведь в htop видно, что во время теста загружено лишь одно виртуальное ядро из 4-х.

UPD:
Запустил на ещё одной машине с hyperthereading:

```
|----|-----|-----|-------|---------|
|CPUs|Cores|Procs| Time  |User time|
|----|-----|-----|-------|---------|
|  8 |  4  |  1  | 6.23  |  6.18   |
|  8 |  4  |  2  | 6.20  |  6.16   |
|  8 |  4  |  4  | 8.38  |  8.33   |
|  8 |  4  |  8  | 19.95 |  11.90  |
|  8 |  4  |  16 | 33.71 |  11.98  |
|----|-----|-----|-------|---------|
```

Тут user time растёт пока не загрузим все 8 виртуальных ядер, а не реальных.

Comment: Используйте нагрузочные тесты. Только тестируйте не на бою, а на изолированном сервере (прямо железка должна быть отдельная, иначе будет фонить), и не все приложения сразу, а по одному.

Comment: С тестами всё понятно.
Но замерять надо и результат в продакшне тоже. Оптимизируем ведь его.

Comment: Странный у вас htop. у меня показывает загрузку всех ядер при соответствующем количестве процессов. А с гипертрейдингом вроде все логично. как я понимаю user time это время на которое ядро отдавало процессу виртуальный процессор. при гипертрейдинге при полной нагрузке ядро грубо говоря выполняет по очереди инструкции то одного виртуального ядра, то другого. в итоге каждое из виртуальных ядер начинает работать в 2 раза медленнее (чем если бы все инструкции были из одного потока), и программа выполняется в 2 раза дольше, получается что ядру пришлось дать в 2 раза больше времени процессу ...

Comment: Ну так htop показывает загрузку по виртуальным ядрам.
И мой синтетический тест, который я привёл в вопросе, нагружает одним процессом одно такое ядро.

Про гипертрединг понятно - это видно из разницы при запуске 2-х и 4-х параллельных процессах на машине с двумя физическими и 4-я виртуальными ядрами.

Непонятно другое: как мне так замерить производительность, чтобы загрузка соседнего виртуального ядра не влияла?

Т.е. грубо говоря, как узнать кол-во времени, которое физическое ядро выполняло мой процесс.

Answer (score 0):

Это многоуровневая задача, вам необходимо использовать разные подходы для разных оптимизаций.

## Sampling

Идея Sampling'а - делаем stack dump с процесса, далее работает статистический анализ. Этот поход показывает методы, которые работают дольше всего чаще всего.

В нем вы должны найти участки вашего кода, которые необходимо ускорять.

## Thread Context Switch Rate

Если у вас синхронный код, то для IO операций происходят частые Context Switch, то есть поток говорит ОС, что "я буду ждать, у меня нет задач", а ОС переключает ядро на другой поток. Это приводит к трате CPU. В этом случае процессор расходует операционная система, а не ваше приложение, а потому падение в производительности сильно размазывается.

См. [тут](https://serverfault.com/questions/14199/how-many-context-switches-is-normal-as-a-function-of-cpu-cores-or-other) рекомендацию, как проверить, что ваше приложение подвержено этой проблеме. Лечить её можно увеличением числа неблокирующих операций (т.е. всё то, что потенциально приведет нас к Wait перед работой IO - это наша проблема).

## Memory Traffic

Если приложение выделяет много памяти, то это создает дополнительную нагрузку на GC. Тут, как и в предыдущем пункте, важно сравнивать с эталоном. Например, для Java/.Net считается, что GC не должен занимать более единиц процента от общего времени работы программы.

Этот пункт можно проверить на Production'е (пункт Sampling скажет, что 5% времени занял GC), однако лечить проблему необходимо локально, проверяя, где больше всего выделяется памяти.

**Важно**: если выделяется много памяти, но время работы GC малое, то проблемы и нет.

## Upper Level

Пункты выше подходят для любого ПО. Однако иногда тормоза могут быть и в вызывающем сервере, т.е. например, когда число активных потоков меньше числа параллельных запросов (тогда пользователь будет ждать, хотя ваше приложение вроде как работает быстро). В таких случаях нет общих решений, всё зависит от конкретного environment'а.

Comment: Вопрос не об этом, тут ващи общие советы не помогают.  
  
Вопрос сводится, как я уже писал выше, к этому:  
  
Непонятно другое: как мне так замерить производительность, чтобы загрузка соседнего виртуального ядра не влияла? Т.е. грубо говоря, как узнать кол-во времени, которое физическое ядро выполняло мой процесс.